# Technology for storing related fixed lenght strings that potentially reference eachother

Tags: storage

We need to store message references from emails and match them with related message references to know the relation between email received by our clients.

We are currently storing this in SQL but i suspect there might be better solutions for storing and searching through this data.

Some more details about the requirements:
We need to store:

```
N 'references' (255 char) linked to an id (bigint) for every email`
```

and we need to look up

```
All id's that match a specific 'reference'
```

since the reference can refer to mail not yet received we need to store all the 'references' regardless of whether they have a related entry.

The 'search' for matching references should be fast (less then 200ms)

We currently search for matching 'references' on demand. but we could amend this to be something that generates 'links' when inserting new references (but that might complicate things).

We currently store this in MySQL but the table is getting very large (several 100 GB)  this seems like an expensive solution.

Are there any technology stacks that do this (much) more efficient?
Maybe lucene/elastic-search?